# How to validate request source for a microservice

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, react-native, microservices

I have a Spring-based Microservice which provides data to a react.js based web client application and a mobile app built using react-native. 
The applications are hosted on the cloud.

I want to allow REST calls from these 2 client applications and block any other request source to protect my application. 
I was thinking of using an APP ID to be passed with every request but that won't protect the service because anyone who has the APP ID will be able to intrude into my REST service. 
Can someone please suggest the best approach to address this problem.

Comment: You should try with passing  `csrfToken` to call your API.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to protect endpoints but most commonly used is **JWT token based authorization**

- Create endpoint eg /auth/api.
- Get the JWT based token from the authentication endpoint, eg auth/signIn - during login process of your app.
- Extract token from the authentication result.
- Set the HTTP header Authorization value as Bearer jwt_token.
- Then send a request to access the protected resources.
- If the requested resource is protected, Spring Security will use our custom Filter to validate the JWT token, and build an Authentication object and set it in Spring Security specific SecurityContextHolder to complete the authentication progress.
- If the JWT token is valid it will return the requested resource to client.

Please go through Spring JWT middleware tutorials

Other way is **Oauth2**, where you need to create Oauth2 server which acts a Authorization server in which clients are assosciated with clientID and client Secret and you approve access using access token.

Comment: In addition to this answer from @vignesh karnika you could restrict access to certain instances(services) on the Cloud infrastructure level as well. For example you could make your api Internal and only reachable to services which are in certain security group. For example in AWS you can add your client applications to specific Security group and only allow instances(with specific IPs from some VPC) to access your API. Read this for more info:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html

Comment: he said 2 client applications not 2 clients . if it is just two clients ,will get ip and add to whitelist. But he want public apps(website and mobile) so its not possible to restrict access to certain instances, Mobile should access service irrespective of his/her network IP